# Kubuntu 18.04 not booting after fresh install

Tags: boot, 18.04, kubuntu

After a fresh install of Kubuntu 18.04.1, my system is not booting at all. After Bios screen, all I get is a white cursor in a black screen.
Before installing this version, I was using a working Kubuntu 14.04. 
What I have tried so far :

- Install with Normal/Minimal installation
- Enable/disable "Download updates" and "Install 3rd party software" at installation
- Use disk partitions as they were before with Kubuntu 14.04 :

  - one 512Mb fat32 partition at start of the disk for booting (EFI)
  - the rest of the disk as an ext4 partition for /
- Wipe out entire disk an use recommended setup (with creates the same setup)
- Use custom disk setup (one single ext4fs partition for /)
- At BIOS boot setup, boot as UEFI
- At BIOS boot setup, boot as Legacy
- Change BIOS settings to use Secure Boot

What I haven't tried yet :

- Installing another flavour of Ubuntu (I don't believe it will change anything)
- Installing an older version of Ubuntu (the whole point in reinstalling was to update)
- Installing another distribution (I would like to stick with Ubuntu)
- Manually installing GRUB from LiveUSB system

I am not even having the Kubuntu logo, so I suppose the issue isn't with graphics drivers.
I am unsure if the problem is with BIOS setup (UEFI/Legacy/Secure boot/etc...) or with Ubuntu itself.

- On one hand, the black screen without any other information straight after BIOS logo suggests that BIOS isn't even finding where to boot the system
- On the other hand, I already tried different boot modes and previous version of Ubuntu booted fine with the same setup. Also, I have a dual boot Windows that is working fine (I force to boot on the other HD via Bios Boot menu).

I am using an Nvidia graphics card, GTX 1080. It required some manual setup to work on 14.04 but I suppose it should work out-of-the-box in 18.04.1 as it is not as new anymore. And my issue doesn't seem graphics-related as I don't get any output.

Any clues on what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue was a faulty usb installation for the Live system. There was an error at installation that I wasn't paying attention to : "An attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from the CD failed".
The installation terminated briefly after that, I thought this was normal process and it wasn't, the installation was actually crashing.

The solution was to write the kubuntu iso to the usb drive **using Rufus instead of Unetbootin**.

As already reported, Unetbootin writes the iso image to USB emulating a CD drive, and this causes the installation to fail. Rufus does the job correctly.

Comment: UNetbootin has been dropped from the Ubuntu default repositories in 18.04 and later because of problems like this.

Comment: @karel Well, that's good to know. But I was using 14.04 when I created the LiveUsb for 18.04...